# Can I use scipy.optimize with numpy.where?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a box-like function with scipy.optimize, and that function is defined with a numpy.where instruction. But the result is a covariance matrix filled with "inf" entries

The function I am trying to fit is box-like: it is equal to F0 outside an "event" and F0-A inside an "event":

```
np.where(np.absolute(miu-x)<=omega/2.0,F0-A,F0)
```

I have tried defining it as a branch function and through numpy.where. In both cases, the end result is not what I intend, as it always gives the following warning:

```
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
```

```py
def func(x, F0, A, miu, omega):
    return np.where(np.absolute(miu-x)<=omega/2.0,F0-A,F0)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0 = pri_values, sigma = sigmas)

# xdata, ydata and p0 are obtained from other files
```

I expect as an output an array of 4 elements with the best fit for each parameter (popt) as well as a 4x4 covariance matrix (pcov). But my result does not converge to the expected values, and the covariance matrix is filled with "inf".